# Pyinstaller to bundle code package with dynamic imports

Tags: pyinstaller, python-3.9, dynamic-import

I have a code that has dynamic module import calls using importlib.import_module and uses Python3.9.10.

The code structure is as below

```
`main.py
.\Main_dependency
      |__ test_calling_script.py
.\Test
      |__ test1.py
      |__ test2.py
      :
      |__ testN.py`
```

My dynamic import is like this where `prm.TestName` is a function within the `test<n>.py`
`test_module = getattr(import_module(f'Test.{prm.TestFile}'), prm.TestName)`

The code works fine when running through terminal/IDE.

I have converted this into a standalone .exe using pyinstaller and am able to run it (which is where my question is).
To make the .exe work, I have specified each dynamic import file path in the hidden import variable of pyinstaller .spec file.

I have some other dynamic imports as well which is bound to make my .spec file messy. Is there a more efficient/clean way to implement the same?

[image: My current .spec file]

I have tried adding the Test directory in `pathex` of .spec file since it is supposed to make pyinstaller add it as a path to search for imports based on the [official documentation](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/spec-files.html#:%7E:text=pathex%3A%20a%20list%20of%20paths%20to%20search%20for%20imports%20(like%20using%20PYTHONPATH)%2C%20including%20paths%20given%20by%20the%20%2D%2Dpaths%20option.)

> pathex: a list of paths to search for imports (like using PYTHONPATH), including paths given by the --paths option.

However, this is not behaving as I expected. Only adding the `Test` path under pathex runs into NoModuleFoundError for the dynamically imported modules.

Comment: Because pathex doesn't actually include those folders in the bundled app it just adds it as a place to search.  You should use datas to add the folder to the bundle and list it in pathex

Comment: @Alexander - do you mean to say add Test folder path to both pathex and datas?

Comment: Yes... create a [mre] if you are still having trouble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. I found out a simple solution to this using the collect_modules from PyInstaller

To include all files within a directory import the collect_modules and store all modules under a variable like so

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_submodules
hiddenimports_DUT_Config = collect_submodules('DUT_Config')
```

All that is left is to assign the `hiddenimports_DUT_Config` variable to `hidden_imports` in Analysis section of the .spec file.

If there are multiple folders to be included i.e folder_1 and folder_2,

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_submodules
hiddenimports_1 = collect_submodules(<folder_1)
hiddenimports_2 = collect_submodules(<folder_2)
all_hidden_imports = hiddenimports_1 + hiddenimports_2

a = Analysis(
    ['main.py'],
    pathex=['folder_1', 'folder_2''],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
    hiddenimports=all_hidden_imports,
```